# Can’t import AWS library to Processing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, import, amazon-dynamodb, processing

I've been trying to work this out for a few days, but I'm starting to give up...
**How do I import and use the Amazon AWS 2.0 SDK in Processing?**

I want to use Amazon DynamoDB to be able to have a few variables (highscores, number of plays, etc.) for my game in the cloud. I originally was going to use a Raspberry Pi I have, but then I found out Amazon provides some DynamoDB use for free, and decided to use that.

I've tried just downloading the jar and dropping it in the Processing window (for it to be added to the "code" folder), using Maven to build the part of the 2.0 SDK  with DynamoDB from CMD, and then putting the generated folder in Processing's libraries folder (Although I wasn't sure exactly what to put there, I tried a few combinations of everything, just the jar, a src folder...). But when I get to the step of, in Processing, writing the `import com.amazonaws.*;` it just tells me the library I'm trying to import doesn't exist...
This was my latest folder sctructure attempt:
[Folder structure attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH633.png).

I'd really appreciate any help, I'm really new to this, and can't find any tutorials specifically about doing this in Processing! I'm happy to give any details needed.
Thanks!

Comment: it help if you can tell us why you want import aws library

Comment: also say which SDK are you using 1.1 or 2.0

Comment: please improve your question, explain what you want do?, what did you already do? if you have some code post it

Comment: @Emiliano The SDK version was already there, but I've added some details and an image about my objective and what I've tried, to hopefully clarify the question a bit! I'm sorry if I'm still missing important details, I'm still getting started with this! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new library to Processing can require quite a bit of work, depending on how many dependencies it needs. Fortunately, it is possible to add support for AWS DynamoDB to Processing (using [AWS SDK for Java 2.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2)). Here is a Processing sketch that shows a simple example:

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.GetItemOutcome;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.PrimaryKey;
//import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;

com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table highScoreTable;

void settings() {
  size(640, 480);
}

void setup() {
  DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_NORTH_1)
            .build()
  );

  highScoreTable = dynamoDB.getTable("stackoverflow-q60122736");

  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  PrimaryKey primaryKey = new PrimaryKey("id", "player-007");
  GetItemOutcome outcome = highScoreTable.getItemOutcome(primaryKey);
  String highScore = outcome.getItem().getString("high-score");

  fill(0);
  text("Hi AWS DynamoDB! The high score is " + highScore + ".", 10, 20);
}
```

This is the official guide to manually installing a library for Processing:
https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library

For Processing to find the jar files related to DynamoDB, you need to create a new directory in the Processing libraries directory (I created this directory on my system: ~/sketchbook/libraries/awsdynamodb111717). In this new directory, you create a "library" directory where you put the jar files mentioned below. Note: the name of the main AWS DynamoDB jar file should be the same as the name of the top level new directory (in my case: awsdynamodb111717).

I downloaded these nine jar files to get AWS DynamoDB to work (Processing seemed unhappy about dashes and dots in the names, so I removed those):

- [awscore111717.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.717/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.717.jar)
- [awsdynamodb111717.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.717/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.717.jar)
- [commonslogging12.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar)
- [httpclient4511.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.11/httpclient-4.5.11.jar)
- [httpcore4413.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.jar)
- [jacksonannotations2102.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.2/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar)
- [jacksoncore2102.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.2/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar)
- [jacksondatabind2102.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.2/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar)
- [jodatime2105.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.5/joda-time-2.10.5.jar)

The first two jar files are from the AWS SDK. The other seven are dependencies.

On my system, the directory structure looks like this:

```
~/sketchbook/libraries/awsdynamodb111717
└── library
    ├── awscore111717.jar
    ├── awsdynamodb111717.jar
    ├── commonslogging12.jar
    ├── httpclient4511.jar
    ├── httpcore4413.jar
    ├── jacksonannotations2102.jar
    ├── jacksoncore2102.jar
    ├── jacksondatabind2102.jar
    └── jodatime2105.jar
```

Finally you need to store your AWS credentials somewhere (for example in a ~/.aws/credentials file; see [Java Code Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html) for more details).

For testing purposes I created a "stackoverflow-q60122736" table with an item for the Processing sketch to retrieve. Processing 3.5.3 was used to test.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! Later today I'll try it out, and let you know if it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, with a couple of small modifications to the code it worked! I removed GetItemOutcome and PrimaryKey, because they didn't work, instead doing this:    

`try {
    Item item = DataTable.getItem("SaveData", 1);
    text(item.getString("GamesPlayed"), 10, 20);
  }   
  catch (AmazonServiceException e) {  
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());  
    System.exit(1);  
  }`  
(Sorry, can't work out how to add line breaks...)  
Anyway, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Although, I've now come across the following problem: When I try to use the standard Processing `loadTable` to load a CSV, it doesn't work, and gives me the following error: Type mismatch, "processing.data.Table" does not match with "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table, is there any way I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the system gets confused about which `Table` class to use. You could try removing the `import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;` line and use `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table` wherever the DynamoDB Table class is used. Using the explicit package this way should solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I do that? I've got `dynamoDB.getTable("ExampleTable");`, if I add it like this: `DataTable = com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table.dynamoDB.getTable("ExampleTable");` it doesn't work, and just tells me `The global variable dynamoDB doesn't exist`, even though it's initialised just above and works without making the change... Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You only need to add the package when you use the class name; the call to `getTable` can remain the same. The `import` statements allow you to skip the package name, until you use two classes with the same name. See my example code.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project and have a great day too!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've got another question: When trying to write a variable on a DynamoDB Table, I get the following error: `The provided key element does not match the schema` My code is like this: `DataTable.updateItem("SampleTable", "2" , "Score", newNumber)`. Any idea what structure I need to use in the updateItem function? I've tried a few different structures and reordered the variables, but can't get it to work... Thanks!

Comment: In that case, it's probably best to create a new question for this specific issue. That will get attention from actual DynamoDB experts and a quicker response. I don't have much DynamoDB experience myself (yet).